# Combine 2 xslt into a single one

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have 2 xslt's. Both are working fine separately one after the other. Is there any way to combine the 2 xslt into a single one?

The first xslt is using accumulators for lookup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
        xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync"
        exclude-result-prefixes ="wd map xs ws"
        version="3.0">           
        <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="CompanyLookup CurrentLookupValue"/>            
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>        
        
        <xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupValue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
            <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Employee_ID/text()" select="."/>
        </xsl:accumulator>
                
        <xsl:accumulator name="CompanyLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
            <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Company/text()" select="map:put($value, accumulator-before('CurrentLookupValue'),string(.))"/>
        </xsl:accumulator>     
        
        <xsl:template match="root/row" mode="report-in-mem">      
            <row>
                <xsl:variable name="company" select="accumulator-before('CompanyLookup')( normalize-space( employee_id ) )"/>                       
                <employeeID><xsl:value-of select="employee_id"/></employeeID>
                <company><xsl:value-of select="$company"/></company>
                <State><xsl:value-of select="State" /></State>
                <Work_days><xsl:value-of select="work_days"/></Work_days> 
            </row>       
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second XSLT is grouping the output of first xslt based on employeeID:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="employeeID">
                <row>
                    <employee_id><xsl:value-of select="employeeID" /></employee_id>
                    <company><xsl:value-of select="company"/></company>                 
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">                            
                        <Data> 
                            <State><xsl:value-of select="State" /></State>
                            <Work_days><xsl:value-of select="Work_days"/></Work_days>
                        </Data> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>    
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input XML is an Aggregated data from two sources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AggregatedData>
   <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
      <wd:Report_Entry>
         <wd:Employee_ID>xyz1</wd:Employee_ID>
         <wd:Company>ABC</wd:Company>
      </wd:Report_Entry>
      <wd:Report_Entry>
         <wd:Employee_ID>xyz2</wd:Employee_ID>
         <wd:Company>ABC</wd:Company>
      </wd:Report_Entry>
   </wd:Report_Data>
<root>
    <row>
        <employee_id>xyz2</employee_id>
        <State>TX</State>
        <work_days>0</work_days>
    </row>
    <row>
        <employee_id>xyz2</employee_id>
        <State>CA</State>
        <work_days>10</work_days>
    </row>

</root>
</AggregatedData>
```

Final output looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <row>
      <employee_id>xyz2</employee_id>
      <company>ABC</company>
      <Data>
         <State>TX</State>
         <Work_days>0</Work_days>
      </Data>
      <Data>
         <State>CA</State>
         <Work_days>10</Work_days>
      </Data>
   </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Well, there are several approaches, first of all, XSLT 3 has the XPath 3.1 function `fn:transform` you can call from XSLT to apply a second (or in general, further) transformation(s) from within XSLT or even XPath or XQuery directly. It shouldn't also not be too difficult to merge those two XSLTs by hand into one, with the exception of the first solution using streaming and the second one not using it but using `for-each-group group-by`, which is not completely streamable.

Comment: The first XSLT uses `mode="report-in-mem"` without declaring it so it doesn't seem to be complete but minimal. Also for the unnamed mode it uses `shallow-skip` which would strip anything not matched by an explicit template so based on that it also seems incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some element names seem to differ in spelling or case of letters but ignoring streaming a fusion of the two XSLTs would be alike

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
        xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync"
        exclude-result-prefixes ="wd map xs ws"
        version="3.0">           
        <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="CompanyLookup CurrentLookupValue"/>            
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>        
        
        <xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupValue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
            <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Employee_ID/text()" select="."/>
        </xsl:accumulator>
                
        <xsl:accumulator name="CompanyLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
            <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Company/text()" select="map:put($value, accumulator-before('CurrentLookupValue'),string(.))"/>
        </xsl:accumulator>     
        
   <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="employee_id">
                <row>
                    <employee_id><xsl:value-of select="employee_id" /></employee_id>
                    <company><xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('CompanyLookup')(employee_id)"/></company>                 
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">                            
                        <Data> 
                            <State><xsl:value-of select="State" /></State>
                            <Work_days><xsl:value-of select="work_days"/></Work_days>
                        </Data> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>    
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In terms of using `fn:transform` and XPath 3 to chain a sequence of XSLTs you can use e.g.

```
let $xslts := ($xslt1, $xslt2)
return
    fold-left(
        $xslts, 
        ., 
        function($source, $xslt) { 
            transform(
                map { 
                    'source-node' : $source, 
                    'stylesheet-node' : $xslt 
                }
            )?output 
        }
    )
```